# Laravel 6 eloquent relationships on multicategories

Tags: php, laravel

I have created 3 database models. One is holding the parent categories, the other one the subcategories and the third one the posts that belong to these categories.

The hierarchy goes as follows:

```
Parent
--Subcategory
----Post1
----Post2
----etc
```

I have created the following relationships on the models:

Subcategories model:

```
public function getCategoryDetails() 
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Categories' , 'id' ,'catId');
}

public function getPosts() 
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Posts' , 'catId' ,'id');
}
```

Posts model:

```
public function getSubcategoryDetails() 
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Subcategories' , 'id' ,'catId');
}
```

This is the code inside the view:

```
    <div class="card mt-2">
    <h5 class="card-header bg-dark text-white d-flex align-items-center">Tillgänliga Kurser från denna arrangör</h5>
        <div class="card-body"> 
        @foreach($posts as $post)
        <div class="card-title">
        {{ $post->getSubcategoryDetails->getCategoryDetails->name }}
        </div>
        <div class="card-title">
        {{ $post->getSubcategoryDetails->name }}
        </div>
        <a href="/kategorier/{{ $post->getSubcategoryDetails->getCategoryDetails->slug }}/kurser/{{ $post->getSubcategoryDetails->slug }}/annons/{{ $post->slug }}">{{ $post->name }}</a>
        <br>
        @endforeach            
        </div>
            <!-- //Project Description Section End -->
    </div>
```

Now this code does almost exactly what I want: It displays the categories for each post and then creates a valid link for each of them.

However, the code above, repeats the categories on every iteration and that is not desired. I want it to display each category only once and the results below it. Example of the expected result:

```
Parent Category 1
--Subcategory 1
----Post1
----Post2
Parent Category 2
--Subcategory 1
----Post1
--Subcategory 2
----Post1
```

But my code will always display the categories and subcategories above every post on each iteration even if the posts belong to the same combination of categories/subcategories. Example of how it works now:

```
Parent Category 1
--Subcategory 1
----Post1
Parent Category 1
--Subcategory 1
----Post2
Parent Category 2
--Subcategory 1
----Post1
Parent Category 2
--Subcategory 2
----Post1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is what I did in the end:

Posts model:

```
public function Subcategory() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Subcategories' , 'id' ,'catId');
}

public function getSubcategoryDetails() 
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Subcategories' , 'id' ,'catId');
}
```

Subcategories model:

```
public function getCategoryDetails() 
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Categories' , 'id' ,'catId');
}

public function getPosts() 
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Posts' , 'catId' ,'id');
}
```

Controller:

```
$organizerDetails   = Organizers::where('slug', $slug)->first();
$posts              = Subcategories::with('getCategoryDetails')->with('getPosts')->whereHas('getPosts', function($q) use ($organizerDetails) {
                    $q->where('organizerId', $organizerDetails->id);
                    })->get()->groupBy('getCategoryDetails.name');
```

View:

```
    <div class="card mt-2">
    <h5 class="card-header bg-dark text-white d-flex align-items-center">Tillgänliga Kurser från denna arrangör</h5>
        <div class="card-body">      
        @foreach($posts as $post => $details)           
            {{ $post }}
            <br>
            @foreach ($details as $singlePost)                        
            {{ $singlePost->name }}
                <br>
                @foreach ($singlePost->getPosts as $course)          
                <a href="/kategorier/{{ $singlePost->getCategoryDetails->slug }}/kurser/{{ $course->getSubcategoryDetails->slug }}/annons/{{ $course->slug }}">{{ $course->name }}</a>
                <br>
                @endforeach
            @endforeach
        @endforeach        
        </div>
            <!-- //Project Description Section End -->
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `map` and `groupBy` on `Collection` (Laravel queries returns collection).

```
$posts->map(function($post, $key) {
    $post['category'] = [
        'name' => $post->getSubcategoryDetails->getCategoryDetails->name,
        'slug' => $post->getSubcategoryDetails->getCategoryDetails->slug,
    ];
    $post['subcategory'] = [
        'name' => $post->getSubcategoryDetails->name,
        'slug' => $post->getSubcategoryDetails->slug,
    ];

    return $post;
})->groupBy(['category.slug', 'subcategory.slug']);
```

**Minimal example**

Suppose your *Post* collection is like this.

```
$posts = collect([
    [
        'title' => 'post title 1',
        'slug' => 'post-title-1',
        'category_id' => 1,
        'subcategory' => 1,
    ],
    [
        'title' => 'post title 2',
        'slug' => 'post-title-2',
        'category' => 2,
        'subcategory' => 2,
    ],
    [
        'title' => 'post title 3',
        'slug' => 'post-title-3',
        'category' => 1,
        'subcategory' => 3,
    ],
    [
        'title' => 'post title 4',
        'slug' => 'post-title-4',
        'category' => 2,
        'subcategory' => 4,
    ],
]);
```

Use `map` to retrieve *category* and *subcategory* of each *Post*. *Post* collection will be modified like this.

```
$posts = collect([
    [
        'title' => 'post title 1',
        'slug' => 'post-title-1',
        'category_id' => 1,
        'subcategory' => 1,
        'category' => [
            'name' => 'category 1',
            'slug' => 'category-1',
        ],
        'subcategory' => [
            'name' => 'subcategory 1',
            'slug' => 'subcategory-1',
        ],
    ],
    [
        'title' => 'post title 2',
        'slug' => 'post-title-2',
        'category' => 2,
        'subcategory' => 2,
        'category' => [
            'name' => 'category 2',
            'slug' => 'category-2',
        ],
        'subcategory' => [
            'name' => 'subcategory 2',
            'slug' => 'subcategory-2',
        ],
    ],
    [
        'title' => 'post title 3',
        'slug' => 'post-title-3',
        'category' => 1,
        'subcategory' => 3,
        'category' => [
            'name' => 'category 1',
            'slug' => 'category-1',
        ],
        'subcategory' => [
            'name' => 'subcategory 3',
            'slug' => 'subcategory-3',
        ],
    ],
    [
        'title' => 'post title 4',
        'slug' => 'post-title-4',
        'category' => 2,
        'subcategory' => 4,
        'category' => [
            'name' => 'category 2',
            'slug' => 'category-2',
        ],
        'subcategory' => [
            'name' => 'subcategory 4',
            'slug' => 'subcategory-4',
        ],
    ],
]);
```

Use `groupBy` on result of *Post* collection

```
$posts->groupBy(['category.slug', 'subcategory.slug']);
```

Output after running on Tinker (`php artisan tinker`).

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#3718
  all: [
    "category-1" => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#3816
      all: [
        "subcategory-1" => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#3817
          all: [
            [
              "title" => "post title 1",
              "slug" => "post-title-1",
              "category" => [
                "name" => "category 1",
                "slug" => "category-1",
              ],
              "subcategory" => [
                "name" => "subcategory 1",
                "slug" => "subcategory-1",
              ],
            ],
          ],
        },
        "subcategory-3" => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#3814
          all: [
            [
              "title" => "post title 3",
              "slug" => "post-title-3",
              "category" => [
                "name" => "category 1",
                "slug" => "category-1",
              ],
              "subcategory" => [
                "name" => "subcategory 3",
                "slug" => "subcategory-3",
              ],
            ],
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
    "category-2" => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#3706
      all: [
        "subcategory-2" => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#3736
          all: [
            [
              "title" => "post title 2",
              "slug" => "post-title-2",
              "category" => [
                "name" => "category 2",
                "slug" => "category-2",
              ],
              "subcategory" => [
                "name" => "subcategory 2",
                "slug" => "subcategory-2",
              ],
            ],
          ],
        },
        "subcategory-4" => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#3721
          all: [
            [
              "title" => "post title 4",
              "slug" => "post-title-4",
              "category" => [
                "name" => "category 2",
                "slug" => "category-2",
              ],
              "subcategory" => [
                "name" => "subcategory 4",
                "slug" => "subcategory-4",
              ],
            ],
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the posts collection doesn't have the category and subcategory. I need to retrieve them by running the relationships, i.e. $post->getSubcategoryDetails->getCategoryDetails->name. The posts collection only has the id of the subcategory and then the subcategory has the id of the main category.

Comment: you can use `map` on collection to get *category* and *subcategory* within Post collection, then use `groupBy` on it. I'll update the answer too.